# display 10 image in a slider

Tags: php, wordpress

[image]

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'testimonial' , 'posts_per_page' => 10,) );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>   
    <div class="testimonial-image">
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail();?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I have the above code it display 10 images in a row I want it to display in a slider 10 image in a slider but it doesnot working 
I have tried bxslider it only add one image in a slider

```
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?> 
<div class="testimonials-carousel-content"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail();?></div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]
Please help I want all images to work inside the slider please have a look on my image

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about [this bxslider](https://bxslider.com/examples/image-slideshow-captions/), I see that you must have one main wrap div with bxslider class (or "testimonials-carousel-content" as you defined in JS-code), and inside DIVs that contain an each image.

So, your code must be like this one:

```
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<div class="testimonials-carousel-content">
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?> 
<div><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail();?></div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and JS code (from example):

```
$(function(){
  $('.testimonials-carousel-content').bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    captions: true,
    slideWidth: 600
  });
});
```

Comment: @Ghugu what exactly isn't working? Did you get any errors? Have you initiated javacript code?

Comment: please look image it display like this

Comment: no error it display only one image not even slider is there any other slider

Comment: @Ghugu could you provide HTML code of result block with image, please? I think it must clear the situation

Comment: <div class="images-slider">
<?php
  $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'testimonial' , 'posts_per_page' => 10,) );?>
 <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?> 
<div class="testimonials-carousel-contents"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail();?></div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; 

?>
</div>

Comment: Now I'm using this the slider start working but one image at a time not 10

Comment: I hope you need something like
Jssor Slider


  https://www.jssor.com/demos/carousel-slider.slider

Answer (score 0):

[Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) looks like a plugin that will suit what you are trying to achieve. There are also loads of [WordPress plugins](https://shapedplugin.com/wordpress-carousel/) that you could try.